# Redirect with GET needs relative path, why?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring MVC and am seeing a rather trivial behavior I don't understand.

Bellow you can find snippets to my Controller (consider I have feed.jsp and feedList.jsp). What I don't understand is why I need the "../list" in one redirect, when the other works without it

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/feed/*")
public class FeedController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "delete/{feedId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String deleteFeed(@PathVariable("feedId") Integer feedId) {
      feedService.delete(feedId);
      return "redirect:../list";
   }
   @RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String saveFeed(@ModelAttribute("feed") Feed feed, BindingResult result) {
      feedService.create(feed);
      return "redirect:list";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `UrlBasedViewResolver` is handling view names as relative to the current request mapping url (citation needed).

Anyway, I always use context-relative absolute paths (starting with a slash): `redirect:/list`. Actually, if your jsp is called "feedList", then your should return `redirect:/feedList`

Comment: what I am trying to do is to redirect from one handler to another... but it's still not working, any idea?